# deductive rule over properties without any resource in protege

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, swrl

friends i wrote an ontology that use same property that i named it " hasPart" for classes via properties restriction  in necessary section of classes in protege."hasPart " property  is without any resource for that i can reuse it .

for example

in httpMassage class:

httpMessage subclassOf  hasPart only (httpRequest or httpReponse)

in httpRequest class:

httpRequest subclassOf  hasPart only (generalHeader or entityHeader or requestHeader or Payload or request_line)

in request_line  class:

request_line subclassOf  has Part only (httpMethod or URl or httpVersion)

i use "hasPart" propety in many other classes too.
then i want to use transitive deductive rule in swrl over my ontology example

hasPart(?x,?y)^ hasPart(?y,?z) -> hasPart(?x,?z)

but when i execute it , swrl display error that outof memory detected please increase the heap size
what is wrong about it?

Comment: "but when i execute it , swrl display error that outof memory detected please increase the heap size what is wrong about it?"  I expect that you ran out of memory.  Reasoning can be expensive.  But note that your rule is probably incorrect in your ontology.  For instance, you said httpMessage can have part httpRequest and httpRequest can have part generalHeader.  That means that an httpMessage could have a generalHeader as a part, but you said that httpMessage could only have httpRequest or ...

Comment: httpResponse as a part.  If a generalHeader can't be an httpRequest or httpResponse, then this would be inconsistent.